# <Error>: CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 150 x 150. error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

When I am running my app on a device (8.0.2) (not the simulator), there are two errors simultaneously.

One is

```
<Error>: CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image size: 150 x 150.
```

Another is

```
error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted
```

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender {

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"choose picture"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"take photos", @"from photo album", nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"choose picture"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"from photo album", nil];
    }

    self.actionSheet.tag = 1000;
    [self.actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}


-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
 if (actionSheet.tag == 1000)
{
    NSUInteger sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    if([UIImagePickerController    isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        switch (buttonIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                break;
            case 1:
                sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                break;
            case 2:
                return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 2)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        }
    }


    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}}

#pragma mark - image picker delegte

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];

     UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self.chooseImage setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //self.productImage.image = image;
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

Comment: You should not be using UIActionSheet. It is deprecated and outmoded. Use UIAlertController.

Comment: I tried to use UIAlertController ,but the problem with "error in __connection_block_invoke_2: Connection interrupted" is still not solved.How to fix it?

Comment: May be due to something else you're not showing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in iOS 10.

1. The Method `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` changes to `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info`
2. Add GCD this way:

   ```
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         UIImage *image = [info   objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
         [self.chooseImage setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         //self.productImage.image = image;
   });
   }
   ```